# I'm sending a test email using perl but it comes back with system can't find path specified

Tags: perl, email, mime-types, mime

I've tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$to = 'abcd@gmail.com';
$from = 'webmaster@yourdomain.com';
$subject = 'Test Email';
$message = 'This is test email sent by Perl Script';

open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");

# Email Header
print MAIL "To: $to\n";
print MAIL "From: $from\n";
print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";
# Email Body
print MAIL $message;

close(MAIL);
print "Email Sent Successfully\n"
```

but it comes back with `The system cannot find the path specified`.

I've also tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use MIME::Lite;

$to = 'abcd@gmail.com';
$cc = 'efgh@mail.com';
$from = 'webmaster@yourdomain.com';
$subject = 'Test Email';
$message = 'This is test email sent by Perl Script';

$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
             From     => $from,
             To       => $to,
             Cc       => $cc,
             Subject  => $subject,
             Data     => $message
             );

$msg->send;
print "Email Sent Successfully\n";
```

but it comes back with `SMTP Failed to connect to mail server: No such file or directory at G:\email_test.pl line 18`

How do I fix this/these issues so I can send an email successfully? These seem to be the two common examples to use when sending email using PERL and I can't get them to work.

Comment: It looks like you're running this on Windows and `/usr/sbin/sendmail` won't exist there. You'll need to give your script the address of an SMTP relay server to use.

Comment: Yep, what @AndrewMedico said - you're opening a pipe into `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t` which is not a valid path on any Windows machine. As an aside, it's good practice to catch errors in *nearest* possible error locations (in this case `open`)

Comment: @AndrewMedico So how would I fix it? By replacing `open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t")` with `open(SMTPserverName)`? If so, would the SMTP server need to be in single quotes etc?

Comment: With MIME::Lite (note: obsolete, not recommended) you can do e.g. `$msg->send('smtp', 'mail.mydomain.com');` where `mail.mydomain.com` is your outgoing SMTP server.

Comment: I Love MIME::Lite! What's the recommended replacement?

Comment: @AndrewMedico Your Mime::Lite seems to work. However, it comes back with `SMTP Failed to connect to mail server: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.` Any ideas? Also, what about my question with the first example?

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting `G:\email_test.pl`, I am assuming you're using a Windows machine. I see `open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");` in your program which refers to a program on a Unix/Linux system.

In Perl, the [Net::SMTP](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/SMTP.html) module comes with almost all Perl distributions. I highly recommend people to use that unless they need to MIME encode mail.

The module is pretty simple to use too although admittedly not as simple as other email modules. `Net::SMTP` assumes you know how SMTP works. Fortunately, the *S* in *SMTP* stands for *Simple*. Of course, the people who called it *Simple* is the same group that thought Emacs was an intuitive program editor.

```
# /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use constant {
    SMTP_HOST     => 'mailhost',
    TO            => 'abcd@gmail.com',
    FROM          => 'efgh@mail.com',
    SUBJECT       => 'Test Email',
    USER          => 'question_guy',
    PASSWORD      => 'swordfish,
};

my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new( SMTP_HOST )       # This is your SMTP host
    or die qq(Cannot create Net::SMTP Object);
$smtp->auth( USER, PASSWORD )                # If you have to use authentication
    or die qq(Can't authenticate into ) . SMTP_HOST;
$smtp->mail( FROM );
$smtp->to( TO );
my $message = "Subject: " . SUBJECT . "\n"
   . "To: " . TO . "\n"
   . 'This is test email sent by Perl Script';
$smtp->data;
$smtp->datasend( $message );
$smtp->dataend;
$smtp->quit;
```

This above wasn't tested, but I was typing it from a program I wrote that used `Net::SMTP`. Take a look at the `Net::SMTP` documentation and play around with it.

Comment: I get `Can't locate object method "new" via package "Net::SMTP" on the line `my $smtp =....`. Net::SMTP is loaded on my machine.

Comment: Interesting. I was expecting maybe a syntax error, but not this. I wrote a five line program where I simply created a `Net::SMTP` object. That worked, or at least I didn't get _that_ error. Possibly that you're not calling the module you think you are? [ikegami](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15806930/368630) has a good suggestion to verify it. You can execute `perldoc Net::SMTP`. Right?