# Perl: can't locate object method bar via package

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am new to this site, so bear with me, If this question has already been answered somewhere else already. I am trying to call a subroutine "bar" from a module "codons1.pm" , and I encounter the error:
Can't locate object method "bar" via package "codons1.pm" (perhaps you forgot to load "codons1.pm"?). The main script looks like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $i = 1;
my $pack = "codons$i\.pm";
require $pack;
(my %temp) = $pack->bar();
print keys %INC ;
```

Thanks to  ([Perl objects error: Can't locate object method via package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689661/perl-objects-error-cant-locate-object-method-via-package)) ,  I was able to verify using %INC, that the module is loaded. 
The module looks like:

```
package codons1;
sub bar{ #some code; 
return (%some_hash);}
1;
```

I am using $i so that I can load multiple similar modules via a loop. Any suggestions is welcome and thanks a lot, in advance.

Comment: You load the file name, but that is not the same as the package name. The package name is defined with the `package` keyword. The file name is irrelevant, unless you use a bareword as the `require` argument. E.g. `use foo`, which looks for `foo.pm`.

Answer (score 4):

Your package is `codons1`, and you're trying to call `codons1.pm->bar`. Either of the following will work correctly:

```
my $pack = "codons$i";
require "$pack.pm";
$pack->bar();
```

or

```
my $pack = "codons$i";
eval "require $pack";
$pack->bar();
```

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do what you're trying to achieve

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
package codons1;
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    return bless {}, $class;
}
sub bar {
    my %some_hash = (temperature=>"35");
    return %some_hash;
}
1;
package main;
my $object = codons1->new(); #creates the object of codons1
my %temp = $object->bar(); #call the bar method from codons1's object
print keys %temp;
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/9Ky99p)

You need to learn basic object oriented programming in Perl. Start with [**perlootut**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html), and then [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html). Read the [Object Oriented Perl chapter](http://blob.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/3145_Chap11.pdf) from freely available Beginning Perl book.

Comment: Or use `Moo` or `Moose`, modern Perl object framework.