# Perl objects error: Can't locate object method via package for class I'm writing

Tags: perl, oop, perl-module

I'm getting the listed error when trying to run code.  I started by looking at the previous answers to similar questions.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689661/perl-objects-error-cant-locate-object-method-via-package)  gave the best info.  It showed me how to look at the item being loaded.

Here is my directory tree:

- Pagerduty/

  - Client.pm
  - Obj.pm
  - test/

    - pagerduty_tester.pl

Here is what the tester currently looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use lib "../..";

use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML qw/LoadFile/;
use Pagerduty::Client;
use Pagerduty::Obj;
use Data::Dumper;

use constant TRUE  => 1;
use constant FALSE => 0;

print($INC{"Pagerduty/Obj.pm"}, "\n");

my $settings = LoadFile("pagerduty.yml");
my $client = Pagerduty::Client->new($settings);

sub create_test_incident{
    my $incident_params = define_test_incident();
    my $incident = $client->create_incident( $incident_params );

}

sub define_test_incident{
    {
        service_key => "<omitted>",
        description => "Test Incident",
        details => {
            detail1 => "Details blah",
            detail2 => "more detail",
        },
    }
}

my $obj = define_test_incident();
# print Dumper($obj);
print Dumper( Pagerduty::Obj->new( $obj ) );

# print Dumper( create_test_incident() )
```

Here is Pagerduty::Obj

```
package Pageduty::Obj;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Structure::Util qw/unbless/;

use constant TRUE => 1;

sub new{
    my $class = shift;
    my $self  = shift;
    # $self->{objCode} = lc($self->{objCode});
    return bless $self, $class;
}

sub serialize{
    my $self = shift;
    unbless($self);
}

sub update_values{
    my $self = shift;
    my $changes = shift;
    if($self->{changes}){
        while(my ($key, $value) = each $changes){
            $self->{changes}->{$key} = $value;
        }
    } else{
        $self->{changes} = $changes;
    }
}

TRUE;
```

Finally, when I run the code I get the following:

```
../../Pagerduty/Obj.pm
Can't locate object method "new" via package "Pagerduty::Obj" (perhaps you forgot to load "Pagerduty::Obj"?)
```

When I cat ../../Pagerduty/Obj.pm I get the code listed above.  This code lives in a library I created.  I put that library in the variable PERL5LIB.  I have the 'use lib ../..' line because I want it work on any computer.  I have been trying to figure out for the past 2 days why this code is not working.  Any ideas?

The other class works accept not being able to create new Pagerduty::Obj with the same error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file is `Pagerduty/Obj.pm`, and you are trying to use the class `Pagerduty::Obj`, but at the top of the module you have

```
package Pageduty::Obj;
```

which should be

```
package Pagerduty::Obj;
```

By the way, the canonical way of adding include directories relative to the location of the script is to use [`FindBin`](https://metacpan.org/pod/FindBin), which sets a scalar variable `$FindBin::Bin` (amongst others) to the absolute path to the directory that contains the Perl program file.

```
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/../..";
```

You may have heard about `FindBin` being broken, but it has been corrected recently in version 16 of Perl 5.

Comment: Awesome!  I have not heard of FindBin so thank you for that.  Also, wow! I feel silly.  Thank you :-)