# Can't locate object method "say_hello" via package "1"

Tags: linux, perl, oop

I just started to learn Perl. When I moved to object orientation I am getting an error like

```
Can't locate object method "say_hello" via package "1" (perhaps you forgot to load "1"?) at ./main.pl line 8.
```

I googled a lot for a solution. Got some similar issues like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689661/perl-objects-error-cant-locate-object-method-via-package). My understanding is it's not a general issue.

Here is my class

```
# MyModule.pm

package MyModule;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    print "calling constructor\n";
}

sub say_hello {
    print "Hello from MyModule\n";
}

1;
```

Here is my test script

```
# main.pl

#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

use MyModule;

my $myObj = new MyModule();
$myObj->say_hello();
```

The code is working perfectly if remove last line from `main.pl`

Comment: This ist he perfect time for you to learn about [Moose](http://p3rl.org/Moose). Check out [this talk by RJBS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKXvG6VKew4) that explains the basics in detail.

Comment: Side note that neither answer mentions: `new MyModule` is called _indirect object notation_ and is generally considered bad practice in Perl because it can confuse the parser and cause  non-obvious problems. I would recommend getting into the habit of saying `MyModule->new` instead.

Comment: @simbabque: I think it's essential to learn the mechanisms behind Perl's object-oriented support before they are lost behind the screen of `Moose` and its derivatives. I continue to achieve far better results using Perl to teach OO instead of something like Java or C++, simply because the concepts are so open and clear.

Comment: @Borodin I agree. But it's still a pain to write it, and Moose is beautiful. Just wanted to mention it, because in the long run it is the right choice for day to day stuff.

Comment: @simbabque: Yes, it would be ideal for the OP doing "day-to-day stuff". But at present they unclear about ideas like `bless`, and there is no day-to-day work. Learning about `Moose`, or preferably its minor variants, should build on top of a thorough understanding of Perl, and I strongly disagree that *"This ist he perfect time for you to learn about Moose"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not creating a new object, and thus `$myObj` is just the return code of the "print" statement (or 1).

You need to `bless`  something and return it.

```
sub new { 
   my ( $class ) = @_;
   print "Calling Constructor\n";
   my $self = {};
   bless $self, $class;
   return $self;
 }
```

That way `$myObj` will actually be an object, not just a return code :)

Comment: You beat me. :) The moon hat fits really well with your picture btw.

Comment: Can you give me an idea about bless?

Comment: If the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html) is unclear, that's probably worth a separate question - because `bless` is pretty fundamental to perl-oo - it 'sets' a class for a data structure.

Comment: @shafeeq, It's how you construct an object. It associates a value with a class.

Answer (score 8):

Your constructor `new` needs to return a *blessed reference* to the data structure you are using to contain the object's information. You have no relevant data here, but you still need to return something

`bless` associates the data with a specific package. In this case, your object should be blessed into `MyModule`, so that perl knows to look for `MyModule::say_hello` when it sees a method call like `$myObj->say_hello()`

Your current constructor returns the value returned by the `print` statement, which is `1` if it succeeded, as it almost certainly does. That is why you see the `"1"` in the error message

> Can't locate object method "say_hello" via package "1" (perhaps you forgot to load "1"?) at ./main.pl line 8.

The most common container for an object's data is a *hash*, so you need to change `new` to this

```
sub new {

    print "calling constructor\n";

    my $self = { };
    bless $self, 'MyModule';
    return $self;
}
```

and then your program will work as it should. It creates an anonymous hash and assigns it to the `$self` variable, then blesses and returns it

Note that this can be made much more concise:

- Without a `return` statement, a subroutine will return the value of the most recently executed statement
- By default, `bless` will bless the data into the current package
- There is no need to store the reference in a variable before blessing it

So the same effect may be achieved by writing

```
sub new {

    print "calling constructor\n";

    bless { };
}
```

Note also that your call

```
my $myObj = new MyModule()
```

is less than ideal. It is called *indirect object notation* and can be ambiguous. It is better to always use a direct method reference, such as

```
my $myObj = MyModule->new()
```

so as to disambiguate the call